# Remove space between header and the page

Tags: html, css

My header has a space above it. I want it to stay to the top without any space. I attached an image that shows the space.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
#example {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #484848;
}
```

```html
<header id="example">
  example
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<body>` element has a default margin. Remove it:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
#example {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #484848;
}
body {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="example">
  example
</header>
```

Comment: why do you only remove the top-margin?

Comment: @Johannes Because the OP said "I want it to stay to the top without any space". If he wants to remove any of the other margins it's trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Many elements come with default margins and/or padding.

This is due to the browser's *default style sheet*.

Add this to your elements where necessary:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Here is a sample default stylesheet browsers might use: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html

---

**EDIT** (since you added more code)

In your case, you need to remove the margins from the `body` element.

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your complete HTML and CSS, the red margin can't be that wide, but anyway: Add

```
html, body { 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

to your CSS

Answer (score 1):

This solves your problem. element body have a margin by default.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

in the top of the css document.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you could do. One is remove `height: 75px` so the div takes only it's natural height (the height of the text).

Or you could add `vertical-align: top` to the `#example` to move the text to the top - div stays the same size here.